# example of `git add --dry-run .` listing file sizes in descending order?

Tags: git, github

I have a wide range of patterns in `.gitignore`, but sometimes things slip through.

Can someone tell me how to **either**:

1. do a dry run of `git add .`/`git add --all` but get some sanity check output alerting me if something really big accidentally showed up.
2. recursively match the contents of .gitignore against the project folder and list the complement with file sizes in descending order

Comment: Consider using `git ls-files --other --exclude-standard` to get a list of currently-untracked files that `git add .` would add. You might also want `git ls-files --modified` to find tracked but modified files. The output from `git ls-files` becomes easily machine-readable when using `-z`, so you can then feed that into a program that checks file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "new commit"`
- list files per size to see if anything is amiss. If so, reset to @~.

To list file size of the new commit:

```
git ls-tree --format="%(objectsize) %(objectname)" @|sort -n -r
```